# SQL - Complexe condition

Tags: sql, laravel

Hello in my SQL i added a column to apply condition on it and my data looks like this:

- Anyword
- Anyword.Anyword
- Anyword.Anyword.Anyword

How can i get all the lines that respect this format - `Anyword.Anyword` only?

If possible, suggest the code in Laravel. Or a simple request on SQL would help too.

Comment: Hi, please include your code and more detail of the errors you're experiencing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you can use:

```
where col like '%.%' and col not like '%.%.%'
```